# getting the width and height when using wrap content

Tags: java, android, layout, android-layout

I am a little puzzled when it comes to getting coordinates or size from a view. At times, when I use WRAP_CONTENT using layout params, and I try to retrieve the width through layout params, I will get the CONSTANT value of WRAP_CONTENT, and the getWidth(), getHeight(), getX(), getY(), getLeft() or whatever method similar to getting the size and coordinate wouldn't work.

How can I achieve to the situation that after wrapping the content, I will be able to retrieve the actual value of the view itself.

Can someone help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

```
int wrapSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
view.measure(wrapSpec, wrapSpec);
```

after that `view.getMeasuredWidth()` and `view.getMeasuredHeight()` should return valid width and height.

Note: `UNSPECIFIED` is a way better approach than picking a very large limit.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()`

Comment: always get 0 . any solution?

Comment: @Ram you must call it after the view has been laid out. Calling this during onCreate(), for example won't work, as the dimensions haven't been measured yet. You can setup a callback to know when yourView has been has been laid out if you need to with: 

yourView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(...)